# Using URL parameters, list posts from category and custom taxonomy

Tags: categories, custom-taxonomy, tags, urls

For example, `http://example.com/?cat=6&tag=books` lists posts that belong to category ID 6 and tagged 'books' (i.e. posts that satisfy both conditions).

Similarly, `http://example.com/feed/?cat=6&tag=books` does the same for feeds.

Now, lets say that my blog has a custom taxonomy called 'edition', with terms 'usa', 'uk', 'china', and so on, under it. The URL `http://example.com/?edition=usa,china` lists posts that belong to both editions 'usa' and 'china'.

And `http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa` lists those posts from category 'Cars' **that also belong to** the custom taxonomy term 'usa'.

### The problem

I use the code below in my functions.php:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts','better_editions_archive');
function better_editions_archive( $better_editions_query ) {

    /* Looks like this line needs to be changed, not sure how */
    if ( $better_editions_query->is_tax( 'edition' ) && $better_editions_query->is_main_query() ) {

        $better_editions_terms = get_terms( 'edition', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
        $better_editions_query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
        $better_editions_query->set( 'tax_query',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $better_editions_terms,
                    'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                )
            )
        );

    }

    return $better_editions_query;
}
```

The code makes sure that if a post is unassigned to any *Edition* (i.e. if a post is not assigned to any term that belongs to the custom taxonomy 'edition'), the post is shown/listed under all term archives/feeds of the custom taxonomy 'edition'.

Now, `http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa` only lists posts that belong to the category 'cars' **and specifically marked** 'usa' (a term belonging to the custom taxonomy 'edition'). It doesn't show those posts that aren't assigned to any term in the custom taxonomy 'edition'. How do I fix this?

(**PS:** [Setting default terms for posts](http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/set-default-terms-for-your-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress-3-0/) isn't an option, as we may add more editions later on.)

---

### Solved but...

I've worked out a solution which you can see as an answer to this question. The bounty still stands, so feel free. :)

Comment: I'm sure it's possible (you can do it with WP_Query, you can build your own WP_Query and you even can create custom rewrite rules to build this query). I'm not sure it will work out of the box, though.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż As long as I have the flexibility of URL parameters, yes.

Comment: Here is info on wp_query and taxonomy queries): http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters Then ckeck registered query_vars (if it's registered use it, and if not, add your own one with `global $wp; $wp->add_query_var('author_more');`

Comment: @its_me, is the issue that your above filter is overwriting the current taxonomy queries present? Or is it having 0 effect on the results?

Comment: @EricHolmes It has zero effect on the results when using the URL parameters, as in, `http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa`

Comment: @Milo **1.** I think `is_tax( 'edition' )` is working fine. The code in my question only doesn't work when using the `category_name`/`edition` URL parameters. So, I think it's more like the conditional statement should include categories also, in some way. **2.** I couldn't find enough examples on the web to understand how to use `posts_where`. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general circumstances, using URL parameters, you can list posts that belong to a specific category AND a custom taxonomy, like this:

```
http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa
```

Where, `category` is the Category base you are using for categories on your site (WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks > Category base); `edition` is the custom taxonomy's base/slug; and `usa` is a term under the custom taxonomy.

If you want to include more than one category/custom taxonomy, these might help:

```
http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa,india
http://example.com/?category_name=cars,books&edition=usa,india
```

And Feeds:

```
http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa,india&feed=rss2
http://example.com/?category_name=cars,books&edition=usa,india&feed=rss2
```

**Further Reading:**

- http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Feeds
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

---

### BUT...

As explained in my question, mine is a complex case, so I've developed a simple work-around. Here goes...

1. The code block in the question makes sure that if a post is unassigned to any Edition (i.e. if a post is not assigned to any term that belongs to the custom taxonomy 'edition'), the post is shown/listed under all term archives/feeds of the custom taxonomy 'edition'.

   **BUT NOW**, I removed that code. Then created a new term under the custom taxonomy 'edition', called 'intl' (International). Any post that want to be displayed under all *Editions* will be assigned to 'intl'. But how do I make sure that all posts assigned to 'intl' show up in all term archives/feeds of my custom taxonomy?

   For that, I now use this code (goes in functions.php):

   ```
   add_filter('pre_get_posts','better_editions_archive');
   function better_editions_archive( $query ) {
       if ( $query->is_tax( 'edition' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
           $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
           $query->set( 'tax_query',
               array(
                   'relation' => 'OR',
                   array(
                       'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                       'field' => 'slug',
                       'terms' => 'intl',
                       'operator' => 'IN'
                   )
               )
           );
       }
       return $query;
   }
   ```

   So now, for instance, `http://example.com/edition/usa/` lists posts that belong to either 'usa' or 'intl' (which are terms under my custom taxonomy 'edition'). Its feed, `http://example.com/edition/usa/feed/` does the same as well.
2. Back to the main problem of the question. How do I list posts that belong to a specific category AND an edition, using URL parameters?

   For example, how do I list posts that belong to category 'cars' AND edition 'usa'?

   This is what the URL should look like: `http://example.com/category/cars/?edition=usa,intl` (since we also want those posts that are shown under all editions i.e. those posts assigned to term 'intl'). As for feeds: `http://example.com/category/cars/feed/?edition=india,intl`

That's it!

*(Special thanks to [@kaiser](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/385/kaiser) for his help.)*

---

### Notes

If you strictly want to modify the main query/loop right within the template, e.g. taxonomy-edition.php (in my case), here's an example as to how it can be done:

```
<?php
$edition_term = get_term( get_queried_object(), 'edition' )->slug;
$better_editions = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'edition',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( $edition_term, 'intl' )
            )
        )
    )
);
?>

    <?php /* Blah, Blah, Blah! */ ?>

<?php if ( $better_editions->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
    <?php while ( $better_editions->have_posts() ) : $better_editions->the_post(); ?>
        <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php /* Blah, Blah, Blah! */ ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Nonetheless, unless you really, really have to, go with `pre_get_posts`.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're having trouble with. You say in your answer, "using URL parameters, you can list posts that belong to a specific category AND a custom taxonomy, like this...", then later, "Back to the main problem of the question. How do I list posts that belong to a specific category AND an edition, using URL parameters?" Can you explain (briefly, as my attention span is juvenile at best) what you need help with?

Comment: @MatthewBoynes I'd clearly stated at the beginning of the 2nd part of my answer: _"As explained in my question, mine is a complex case..."_ i.e. I was using a code (see Q) that "makes sure that if a post is unassigned to any Edition (i.e. if a post is not assigned to any term that belongs to the custom taxonomy 'edition'), the post is shown/listed under all term archives/feeds of the custom taxonomy 'edition'." Clear now? :)

Answer (score -3):

You may have to look into using wp_query. in which you set your own query to display any category you like, and then when done, reset it to the default behaviour.

Comment: The code in question is already working with query - main one. How does creating secondary query would address the question?

Comment: What I as thinking is creating a new query, in which it addresses both the main query in question + whatever that is not displayed. I did not provide code because I assumed that my answer would provide enough guideline for the person who asked the question. Obviusly not many people like this approach, however I used it myself and it works just fine.