# Is it good practice to search for custom posts based on custom field values?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, search

I am building a theme for a local roofing company and we need to implement a solution for users to be able to search through custom posts and find what they're looking for based on custom field values.

For example, a user should be able to select that they are looking for all posts that match:

- roofColor = green
- roofType = shingles
- roofCity = chicago
- etc..

There will be hundreds of projects (custom post entries) to search through.  I'm interested in best practices here.  **Is it okay to be using custom fields for my custom posts in this example** and to search for posts that have the matching custom field values?  I have heard that the way wordpress stores values like this in the db would make it inefficient or slow, so **I'm wondering if it would be better to build my own database to handle the special values for each roofing project?**

Thank you for your time and insight, it's greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect use case for [Custom Taxonomies](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies).

And unless you plan to customize the admin backend, the [Codepress Admin Columns](http://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/) plugin could be useful for filtering the posts using those new taxonomies.

**Edit (2014.01.23):**

Yes, you could build a "search form" where you would list the available taxonomies.

The `get_categories()` function will be useful to retrieve all the terms of a taxonomy, using the "taxonomy" parameter. Refer to [the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories).

With that method, you could produce a dropdown list for each taxonomy.

The selection of that dropdown could generate a URL that includes the necessary parameters for the query: example.com/?roofcolor=green,red&roofcity=chicago+new-york ...

This would result in a page that displays the filtered content.

It seems to me that this is a pretty simple method of achieving what you want.

Here are two articles with more information about how to write complex taxonomy queries:

- [Using URL parameters, list posts from category and custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104927/using-url-parameters-list-posts-from-category-and-custom-taxonomy)
- [How to pass URL parameters for advanced taxonomy queries with multiple terms for one custom taxonomy](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25999/how-to-pass-url-parameters-for-advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-multiple-terms-for)

Comment: So with this method I would be able to set up a "Search" module where visitors could select all specific Taxonomies that would apply to the kind of post their looking for?  In other words, selecting posts that belong to a specific set of taxonomies?